# I cannot ping the destination address of the sensor's destination address

Tags: networking, ip, connection

I am trying to connect a sensor to my laptop. This happens through a media converter where two cables are plugged into it from the sensor. Then, (a third) an ethernet cable is connected from media converter to my docker station (thinkpad) which I have connected to my laptop.

Now, I setup the my local wired network with an address of 192.168.1.255 and a gateway of 255.255.255.0.

Then, I open wireshark and I can clearly see the sensor (192.168.1.100) is sending data frames to destination 192.168.1.200. I can also see from `arp -a` that the Mac address associated to what I think is the sensor corresponds to the sensor's mac address indeed.

When looking at `arp -a` I also see the following:

```
192.168.1.200 at (incomplete) on en6  if scope (ethernet)
```

Trying to ping `192.168.1.200` also fails to connect. I have no clue what the problem could be. The only thing I realized was that my media converter has a number of light which all are on. However, the one labelled "host" is blinking rather than having a continous light on. I dont know whether that means something.

Any suggestion to what I can do?

Comment: Does a device with such an address actually exist on your network? How do you know the sensor isn't just sending data to the void?

Comment: no idea to be honest. I just now that from an old manual that I should be able to access a webinterface of address 192.168.1.201. Now the sensor seems to be sending to .200 instead. I tried both but neither were reachable

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the sensor is sending blindly to that address, but that doesn't imply that the address exists. IP addresses don't just exist out of nowhere – there has to be an actual device connected and assigned such an address in order for it to respond.

Right now the network you've described has two devices: the laptop and the sensor. Your laptop clearly isn't 192.168.1.200 (because it's .255, even though that's not valid<sup>1</sup>, but nevermind for now), and your sensor isn't 192.168.1.200 either (because it's .100 and because it's sending data *to* .200, so that definitely rules out the sensor itself being .200), so the only remaining option is that there must be a third device with that address (some sort of data collector) – which you don't have.

So the most likely problem is that you're physically missing some additional device that the manual is talking about.

---

<sup>1</sup> In IPv4, the last address of a subnet (which is x.x.x.255 when using a 255.255.255.0 netmask) is reserved as the "broadcast" address and is not valid to be assigned to an individual device.

You should move the laptop to another address in the subnet (such as .254 or .123). On the odd chance that the *media converter* is supposed to be .200 or .201 (I don't know what the manual says), using a non-reserved address will likely give you better results.

Comment: I am certain that there is no third device needed. For reference: https://velodynelidar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/63-9243-Rev-E-VLP-16-User-Manual.pdf

Comment: So the manual says that .201 is the sensor, but your packet capture says that .100 is the sensor. In that case, have you tried opening a web interface at `http://192.168.1.100`?

Comment: yes, that also wont load up anything

Comment: Did you fix the laptop's IP address to not use the reserved broadcast address? Does 192.168.1.100 at least show up in the ARP cache?

Comment: So my ARP cache shows a it different outpuit than yesterday (where I used a differnt laptop) . 
I have fixed the wired connection to use: 192.168.1.222 and gateway of 255.255.255.0

Now:
`
_gateway (255.255.255.0) at <incomplete> on enxf4a80d13a94c
_gateway (192.168.0.1) at e8:48:b8:ab:98:84 [ether] on wlp0s20f3
? (192.168.0.2) at 5c:c1:d7:80:26:64 [ether] on wlp0s20f3
? (192.168.0.0) at <incomplete> on wlp0s20f3`

Comment: I should say my wireshark still shows udp packets being received at this point from 192.168.1.100, and I can see from the headers that they indeed are received from the sensor (vendor name etC)

Comment: but the manual is old and could eb outdated

Comment: It could just be that someone else has re-configured the sensor's IP address previously (through the web interface). Also, gateway? 255.255.255.0 is the netmask (subnet mask), do not specify it as a gateway address.

Comment: ahh okay thanks. Not understanding why I can  see from wireshark that Iam receiving from .100 but cannot ping it